# Select query to remove non-numeric characters value and get top value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Select query to remove non-numeric characters value and get top value.

```
select stuff(Round, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', Round)-1, '')  from Table_LKP_RoundInfo
```

I have Data like below in my Round column.

```
Round1
Round5
Round18
Round9
```

From above select query I am getting non-numeric list like below

```
1
5
18
9
```

and now I need top value result from above 4 values like top value is 18. I need output as 18 in above select query.

Comment: Cast it into interger and then use the MAX aggregation function

Comment: Please give me answer will helpful for me. @Mittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve by this

```
select 
Max(CONVERT(int, stuff(Round, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', Round)-1, '')))
from Table_LKP_RoundInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace the `Round`;

```
select MAX(cast(REPLACE(Round, 'Round', '') as int)) MaxRound
from Table_LKP_RoundInfo
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, your query also giving correct result but I prefer mittal answer. @Rainman

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substring()` with `patindex()` function to achieve the above with max values

```
select max(substring(Round, PATINDEX('%[^ROUND]%', Round), LEN(Round))) 
from Table_LKP_RoundInfo
```